# Como obtener el nombre de todos los parents de un JSON y almacenarlos en un array

Tags: c#, json

Estoy tratando de obtener y almacenar en una lista los nombres de los parents del siguiente JSON.

Los parents que busco almacenar son el "3" y el "5". Pero la solución que busco no podría ser específica, estos números se generan de forma aleatoria.

Necesitaría almacenar en una lista una cosa similar a esta.

```
lista[0] = "3"
lista[1] = "5"
```

Como máximo almacenaría 50 elementos. Estoy trabajando con la librería Newtonsoft y este JSON es una respuesta de la API de Philips Hue.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

JSON:

```
{
   "3":{
      "state":{
         "on":true,
         "bri":254,
         "hue":43690,
         "sat":140,
         "effect":"none",
         "xy":[
            0.2566,
            0.2524
         ],
         "ct":153,
         "alert":"select",
         "colormode":"hs",
         "mode":"homeautomation",
         "reachable":false
      },
      "swupdate":{
         "state":"noupdates",
         "lastinstall":"2020-01-30T12:22:09"
      },
      "type":"Extended color light",
      "name":"Hue color lamp 1",
      "modelid":"LCT015",
      "manufacturername":"Signify Netherlands B.V.",
      "productname":"Hue color lamp",
      "capabilities":{
         "certified":true,
         "control":{
            "mindimlevel":1000,
            "maxlumen":806,
            "colorgamuttype":"C",
            "colorgamut":[
               [
                  0.6915,
                  0.3083
               ],
               [
                  0.1700,
                  0.7000
               ],
               [
                  0.1532,
                  0.0475
               ]
            ],
            "ct":{
               "min":153,
               "max":500
            }
         },
         "streaming":{
            "renderer":true,
            "proxy":true
         }
      },
      "config":{
         "archetype":"sultanbulb",
         "function":"mixed",
         "direction":"omnidirectional",
         "startup":{
            "mode":"safety",
            "configured":true
         }
      },
      "uniqueid":"00:17:88:01:04:0c:5b:8b-0b",
      "swversion":"1.46.13_r26312",
      "swconfigid":"52E3234B",
      "productid":"Philips-LCT015-1-A19ECLv5"
   },
   "5":{
      "state":{
         "on":true,
         "bri":236,
         "alert":"select",
         "mode":"homeautomation",
         "reachable":false
      },
      "swupdate":{
         "state":"noupdates",
         "lastinstall":"2020-02-21T12:27:34"
      },
      "type":"Dimmable light",
      "name":"Hue white lamp 1",
      "modelid":"LWB010",
      "manufacturername":"Signify Netherlands B.V.",
      "productname":"Hue white lamp",
      "capabilities":{
         "certified":true,
         "control":{
            "mindimlevel":2000,
            "maxlumen":806
         },
         "streaming":{
            "renderer":false,
            "proxy":false
         }
      },
      "config":{
         "archetype":"classicbulb",
         "function":"functional",
         "direction":"omnidirectional",
         "startup":{
            "mode":"safety",
            "configured":true
         }
      },
      "uniqueid":"00:17:88:01:04:a5:ab:fc-0b",
      "swversion":"1.46.13_r26312",
      "swconfigid":"322BB2EC",
      "productid":"Philips-LWB010-1-A19DLv4"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como te especifiqué en tu anterior pregunta debes recorrer el diccionario deserializado. Te paso un ejemplo

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    public partial class MyClass
    {
        public State State { get; set; }
        public Swupdate Swupdate { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Modelid { get; set; }
        public string Manufacturername { get; set; }
        public string Productname { get; set; }
        public Capabilities Capabilities { get; set; }
        public Config Config { get; set; }
        public string Uniqueid { get; set; }
        public string Swversion { get; set; }
        public string Swconfigid { get; set; }
        public string Productid { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Capabilities
    {
        public bool Certified { get; set; }
        public Control Control { get; set; }
        public Streaming Streaming { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Control
    {
        public long Mindimlevel { get; set; }
        public long Maxlumen { get; set; }
        public string Colorgamuttype { get; set; }
        public List<List<double>> Colorgamut { get; set; }
        public Ct Ct { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Ct
    {
        public long Min { get; set; }
        public long Max { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Streaming
    {
        public bool Renderer { get; set; }
        public bool Proxy { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Config
    {
        public string Archetype { get; set; }
        public string Function { get; set; }
        public string Direction { get; set; }
        public Startup Startup { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Startup
    {
        public string Mode { get; set; }
        public bool Configured { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class State
    {
        public bool On { get; set; }
        public long Bri { get; set; }
        public long? Hue { get; set; }
        public long? Sat { get; set; }
        public string Effect { get; set; }
        public List<double> Xy { get; set; }
        public long? Ct { get; set; }
        public string Alert { get; set; }
        public string Colormode { get; set; }
        public string Mode { get; set; }
        public bool Reachable { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Swupdate
    {
        public string State { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset Lastinstall { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var jsonToDeserialize = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("data.json");
            var dataDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, MyClass>>(jsonToDeserialize);

            // RECORRER PARENTS
            foreach (var key in dataDeserialized.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"HELLO KEY {key}");
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataDeserialized[key])); // EN Keys tienes las claves

                Console.WriteLine(); 
                Console.WriteLine();

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que utilices el **`JObject.Parse`** de la librería Newtonsoft y obtengas las propiedades del objeto principal.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
JObject root = JObject.Parse(json);
IEnumerable<JProperty> properties = root.Properties();

List<string> lista = new List<string>();

foreach (JProperty prop in properties)
{
    if (lista.Count >= 50) break;
    lista.Add(prop.Name);
}
```

> Si dentro del json vienen más propiedades que no son número (en string) entonces puedes validar dentro del `foreach` que el nombre a agregar sea un número entero.

---

Otra forma de hacerlo es por Linq:

```
JObject root = JObject.Parse(json);

List<string> lista = root.Properties().Select(c => c.Name).Take(50).ToList();
```

> De igual forma si necesitas validar los nombres de las propiedades lo que debes hacer es llamar al método `Where`.